# How to download or install Gitlib as a standalone library with recent versions of pip?

Tags: python, git, cygwin, pip

This is a very simple problem, but I’m completely stuck on how to solve it. I couldn’t even found a way for just downloading.
The website don’t give anything for downloading it outside pypi and without smug.

```
$ pip install --allow-external gitlib gitlib
Collecting gitlib
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gitlib (from versions: )
  Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified gitlib to allow).
No matching distribution found for gitlib
```

Using the required options doesn’t solve the problem.

```
$ pip install --allow-all-external --allow-unverified gitlib gitlib==0.5
Collecting gitlib==0.5
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gitlib==0.5 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for gitlib==0.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pypi is only a list of registered projects -- if the package is listed at a download URL, you will need to follow that path to get the actual code to install.

In your case, you could `git clone` or `pip install` from git://mcnabbs.org/smug.git.  If there's issues cloning or downloading, that's not something anyone here would be able to help you out with -- the package maintainer has decided to self-host his code.

More generally, pip interacts with pypi.  Pypi is a package index for code that is not in the standard library.  Much of this code is third-party/non-official.  It's important to note that there is *no promise* of quality, functionality, or ability to install this code directly from pip.

In the case of ["Gitlab" as per pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Gitlib), there's no promise that the code is actually true to its marketing of being a "Pythonic low-level Git library", there's no guarantee that the download URL is direct (or correct or even working), and it's a perfect example of the value of knowing that this information is maintained by the person that registered that package on pypi.

Comment: Siggh, [the package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Gitlib) doesn’t have a download url. The purpose of it’s registration on pypi is only for providing a way to download it separately, and that way is pip.`git://mcnabbs.org/smug.git`isn’t the url of Gitlib but the url of an another project.

Comment: On the page "`Download URL: git://mcnabbs.org/smug.git`" -- the purpose of registration is to make others aware of code that exists.  You will likely need to `git clone` and install a local package if you're sure you really want to use this package.

Comment: `git clone git://mcnabbs.org/smug.git`won’t clone Gitlib, it will clone smug which is an another project that doesn’t let to use Gitlib as a libarary.

Comment: @user2284570: did you try it, and look in the `gitlib` directory?  (See its `setup.py`, which contains `provides=['smug', 'gitlib']`..)

Comment: Well, unfortunately, that's the answer, even if it's not good news for you.  There's no promise of code quality, directness of download URL, or functionality -- pypi is only a registration.

Comment: @tristan : and what the pip command would download ? *(my assumption is that it use a non listed different download url)*

Comment: pip interacts with pypi.  stop making the assumption that `pip install blah` should work the way you want and please read my explanation.

Comment: @DSM : the`'smug'`in`provide=`and other stuff prevent it from building outside smug.

Comment: this is third-party code.  again, please read my answer.  pip or pypi makes no promise that third-party code will work the way you want it to.  the more important lesson is learning how pip interacts with pypi.

Comment: Everything tristan says here is good advice. You *can* get pip to install direct from a git repo. Look up pip install git repo. It's in the pip documentation.  Looks like you can do that here with the smug download url and then just use the package you want,  ignoring the package called smug that you don't. Do look at how pip and pypi interact too.

Comment: @user2284570 See http://dpaste.com/0GTT2RY for a clean install of the library and example of importing it ready for use without imporitng smug.